# Why mud area won't match after prime and paint?

Tags: drywall

I cut out two feet of drywall around basement wall, tape,mud and sanded. I used drywall primer and painted. Why do I have a lighter color where I mud around my basement wall?

Comment: Tell us about the paint… was it a color match, or was it the original? If original, how old was it?

Answer (score 1):

The paint may not have dried enough yet.

The paint may not be an exact enough match. If this is the issue, painting the whole wall is one fix; "feathering" the edges so the new paint blends into the old may be another.

The plaster texture may not be an exact match. If this is the problem, additional sanding if the patch and/or it's surroundings may make things better, or may make things worse; you sorta have to experiment. Or, again, do a skim-coat of new plaster across the whole wall followed by repainting it all. A thick primer may serve the same purpose of smoothing the surface.

If the difference is minor, you may want to just ignore it for a few weeks and see if you still notice it after that, or get someone else to look at it without telling them what to look for. Right now you know exactly where to look and any slight difference will jump out at you. You may find that for others, and eventually for yourself, this isn't enough difference to be worth worrying about. I can still find my patches from a few years ago, but I have to be actively looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

If the "mud" was applied thick, it may be pulling in moisture from the paint.

Try allowing more curing time and applying another coat or two.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the problem is that the new paint is *darker* than the old paint, and that's because the old paint has faded in the sun light coming in through the windows.

In this case, it's in a basement, so there's probably not a lot of sunlight, so it's likely that even if the patch repair paint came out of the same can as the original paint, the old paint is dirty (even if slightly) and the new paint isn't.